# Video is not autoplaying (with playsinline and byte-ranges) in Safari (16.3) on macOS (13.2.1) while charging

Tags: html, video, safari

Safari (16.3) on macOS (13.2.1) is not autoplaying the video, even though `playsinline` `autoplay` and `muted` are set within the HTML element, byte-ranges are correct server side, Media is not blocked for this host within Safari settings. It stills shows the play button in some cases.

I am trying to figure out what it is. At the moment my best bet seems a bit odd at first.
If the charging cable is connected it does not autoplay.
If the charging cable is disconnected is does autoplay.
I assume that charging is somehow something like a save-energy-mode?

[Charging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVZnD.jpg)

[Not Charging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWNF6.jpg)

Anybody knows something?

https://codepen.io/anothercodepen/pen/yLxVZOq

```
<video playsinline muted loop autoplay class="video" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```